# Sending HTTP 1.1 GET requests with socket.send, python

Tags: python, linux, sockets, unix, networking

I am trying to send a Get request to the google server by,
`GET / HTTP/1.1\r\nHost: www.google.com\r\n\r\n`
via Python3 sockets.send function. The code for sending is given below :

```
import socket
buffer = input()     #filled the with 'GET / HTTP/1.1\r\nHost: www.google.com\r\n\r\n'
client = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
client.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
target = "www.google.com"
port = 80
client.connect((target,port))    
client.send(buffer.encode()) 
while True:
    recv_len = 1
    response = ""
    while recv_len:
        data        = client.recv(4096).decode(errors="ignore")
        recv_len    = len(data)
        response    += data
        if recv_len < 4096:
            break
    print(response)
```

But I am receiving no data back from the server.
Can somebody help me with this? I tried similar questions, but most are concentrated on the use of `\n` in the request.

Comment: *"But I am receiving no data back from the server. "* - using your code I receive data back, i.e. the `print` statement actually prints data. It is unclear what you are doing differently. I recommend that you show the full code where you have the problem with and not only the parts you deem relevant. See also [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: I have edited my code, please check

Comment: I can see that you use `input` to get the string. I know no easy way to enter a `\r` (carriage return) not a `\n` (newline) in a string. If you type `\r\n` at an input prompt you will get the 4 character backslash, r, backslash, n (`'\\r\\n'` as a Python string) instead of the two characters `'\r\n'` (or `'\x0d\x0a'`).

Comment: Thank you for pointing out the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is with the line

```
buffer = input()
```

As [Serge Ballesta](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3545273/serge-ballesta) mentioned, `input()` function reads `\r` as two characters, `"\"` and `"r"`. Using

```
buffer = sys.stdin.read()
```

and  piping the GET request to the program file will solve the issue.

```
echo -ne "GET / HTTP/1.1\r\nHost: www.google.com\r\n\r\n" |python3 temp.py
```